# Uploading large files with Django: How should one go about doing this?

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I have to upload >= 20 GBs of data with Django.
Should I break the file into chunks and then upload it with some kind of a checksum to maintain integrity or does Django implicitly does it?

Will it be better if I use FTP instead of regular HTTP for such large files?

Comment: what is the method you are using to send file to your server ?. Do you have a front-end site or apis for that.

Comment: For now, I am considering HTTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django uses so-called [Upload Handlers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/) to upload files, and has a related setting called FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE (default value of 2.5Mb). Files smaller than this threshold will be handled in memory, larger files will be streamed into a temporary file on disk. I haven't yet tried uploading files larger than about 1Gb, but I would expect you can just use django without problems.

Comment: Ok, So should I split the file into chunks before uploading? Or is that too done by Django?

Comment: You don't have to split it up, it gets streamed by django which makes it very easy